# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am using VS 2017 to develop my .NET application. I have written following code to retrieve data from table in api

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Index")]
public IEnumerable<Strings> Index()
{
    var list = db.Strings.Select(x => new { x.Iid, x.Value, x.Description, x.Itype }).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

How the casting is possible? I have changed IEnumerable to IList but the problem exists. I don't want to create ViewModel for that.

Comment: Your function is supposed to return `IEnumerable<Strings>` but you are returning a collection of an anonymous object..

Comment: Here Strings is a model class.

Comment: instead of `.Select(x => new {`... (anonymous object), use `.Select(x => new Strings {`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
public IEnumerable<Strings> Index()
    {
        var list = db.Strings.AsEnumerable();
        return list;
    }
```

or if you want to project to a model:

```
        public IEnumerable<Strings> Index()
    {
        var list = db.Strings.Select(x => new Strings { Iid = x.Iid, Itype = x.Itype, Description = x.Description, Value = x.Value } ).AsEnumerable();
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: it certainly is unnecessary if db.Strings is a collection of entities. I was just being explicit versus ToList.

Answer (score 8):

You're creating a list of anonymous objects with `Select(x => new …)` and then attempting to return that as an `IEnumerable<Strings>`, which is why you're getting the error.

You can't return anonymous objects from methods anyway (1), so either change the query to return a list of `Strings` or use an intermediate object to represent the data.

(1) well, you can, but not in a usable form.